# java открыть ссылку в браузере в linux

Tags: java, браузер

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

не работает в ubuntu хотя,

```
Desktop.isDesktopSupported()&&Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE))==true
```

Chrome как-будто пытается запуститься, но не запускается(На несколько секунд в левом верхнем углу появляется значок браузера с иконкой загрузки) Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: `$ xdg-open https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/623259` запускает браузер?

Comment: из терминала да

Comment: а при запуске из java выдает exception java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "xdg-open": error=2, No such file or directory